# How get Dynamic value to the JSON obj?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below  Json data which fetch to mysql . 
Problem.  In JSON data have opt1,opt2,opt3......opt7.

Below I am gettings opt1..7 values by for loop but I got  each opt1...7 value  undefined. Why?

JSON data:

```
{"qz_id":"15","qzn_id":"14","ins_user_id":"1","qnumber":"8","quiz_question":"jdfkjf dkfj dkjfkd kid jfkjdk fdkjfk djfkdjfkd kfkd fk djfkd jfk d",
            "opt1":"jkj","opt2":"kjkj","opt3":"kjkj","opt4":"kjkjkjk","opt5":"","opt6":"","opt7":"","right_opt":"opt1","qns_explanation":"",
            "Answeroption":"0","q_mark":"0","qns_neq_mark":"0",
            "qns_DifficultyLevel":"1","cdate":"2017","stt":"In-active","del_stt":"No","quiz_name":"ssdsds demo","exam_id":"5","sec_id":"6"}
```

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "quiz_process.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {  
   var obj=JSON.parse(data);
   /*opt a*/
   var optv="";
   var optionv="";
   for(var i=1;i<=7;i++) {
     optv='opt'+i;
     optionv = optv+'::'+obj.optv;
     console.log(optionv);
   }

 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to access an objects property via a variable, you'll have to change your syntax a bit:

`optionv = optv+'::'+obj[optv];`

Otherwise, when you do `obj.optv` you're trying to access an `optv` property of the object which does not exist in your case.